# group call made time by week - MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables A and B.
A holds data for outbound calls. (call made time & phone number).
B holds data for inbound calls. (call received time & phone number).

I have to show data for all outbound calls that received an inbound call from the same number within 7 days after placing an outbound call. If i don't get call from that number within 7 days, then that outbound call should not be considered.
EX: I made an outbound call from '9999999999' number on march 1st and i have received an inbound call from same number '9999999999' on march 5th. I have to show this call in my report.

Another scenario to be considered is: If i make an outbound call on march 1st and march 3rd etc, then i have to consider only first made outbound call in one week starting from the outbound call and show in results only if i have an inbound call for that march 1st made call.

**Data for one of the phone numbers from my tables is like:**
**Table A:**

### Phone number| Outbound call time (in datetime)

9999999999  | 2015-12-23 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2015-12-29 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2015-12-30 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-05 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-06 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-07 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-07 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-08 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-19 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-21 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-22 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-26 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-28 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-29 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-02 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-03 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-04 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-09 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-11 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-12 xx:xx:xx

**Table B:**

### Phone number| inbound call time (in datetime)

9999999999  | 2016-01-08 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-13 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-19 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-31 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-11 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-12 xx:xx:xx

My output should be like:

### Phone number| outbound call time |inbound call time  (in datetime)

9999999999  | 2016-01-05 xx:xx:xx|2016-01-08 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-19 xx:xx:xx|2016-01-19 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-01-26 xx:xx:xx|2016-01-31 xx:xx:xx
9999999999  | 2016-02-04 xx:xx:xx|2016-02-11 xx:xx:xx

My query is:

```
SELECT a.phonenumber, Min(a.outboundcall), Min(b.inboundcall)  
FROM TableA a  
join TableB b  
ON (a.phonenumber=b.phonenumber)  
WHERE (a.outboundcall < b.inboundcall)  
AND (DATEDIFF(MI, a.outboundcall,b.inboundcall) between 0 AND 10800)  
group by a.phonenumber,  
         DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101', a.outboundcall)/7*7, '19000101'),  
         DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19000101', b.inbouncall)/7*7, '19000101')  
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Time should also be considered.
Can anyone please help me in writing a query for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.phonenumber, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,PhStartDates.stDate,a.outboundcall)/7), 
FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,PhStartDates.stDate,b.inboundcall)/7),    
MIN(a.outboundcall), MIN(b.inboundcall)
FROM TableA a  
join TableB b  
ON a.phonenumber=b.phonenumber
join (SELECT phonenumber, Min(outboundcall) as StDate
FROM TableA 
group by phonenumber) as PhStartDates
ON a.phonenumber=PhStartDates.phonenumber
WHERE (a.outboundcall < b.inboundcall)
AND FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,PhStartDates.stDate,a.outboundcall)/7) = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,PhStartDates.stDate,b.inboundcall)/7);
GROUP BY a.phonenumber, FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,PhStartDates.stDate,a.outboundcall)/7), FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day,PhStartDates.stDate,b.inboundcall)/7)
ORDER BY 1,4,5;
```

Comment: Nope. It didn't work. I used group by so that it will check for every outbound call for that phone number. If not, it will only select one record for one phone number.  
Lets say if i make an outbound call on march 1st, then query should check if there is an inbound call for that number from march 1st to march 8th. Also, it should consider only the first made outbound call from march 1st to march 8th. This repeats for same or any other phone number again and again.

Comment: Nope. It didn't work. Can i know why you have used this in your query. DATEPART(week, a.outboundcall) = DATEPART(week, b.inboundcall)

Comment: to say that both dates belong to the same week of the year. i thought thats what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Actually they doesn't need to be in the same week, but the difference should be 7 days. 
Lets say i made an outbound call to '9999999999' several time in seven days period and i have got callback from '9999999999' in that 7 days period, then i have to consider first made outbound call datetime for '9999999999' in that seven day period and first callback datetime. Again this may repeat for the same number after couple of week or months.

Comment: thats way too confusing though, not for a computer program but also for a human being to understand: let me put some examples and you tell how you are gonna take the outbound and inbound dates from this example, OK? Outbound call days: day 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 16; Inbound calls: day 9, 10, 20, 22, 23, 24;

Comment: I know, this is a bit complicated to understand. But, i appreciate your response. For your example,
[outbound call day, inbound call day]:[8,9],[16,20]

first made outbound call= 1st and there is no inbound call from 1st to 8th (7 day difference)
so, now next first outbound call would be 8th and there is an inbound call within a 7 day period on 9th. So this should be in the result as well.
Again next first outbound call would be on 16th and there is an inbound call within a 7 day period on 20th. So this should be in the result as well.

Comment: so, you start from the first outbound call day and keep adding 1 week for each comparison?

Comment: Yup. And that first outbound call day will vary for each phone number. I am not sure if i have to write a stored procedure for this.

Comment: I have updated my answer (there's no way for me to test unfortunately), I would agree that a stored procedure would have made things way simpler for this purpose

Comment: Thanks. Looks like, this worked. Can you brief me what this query is doing.

Comment: i certainly can, what the inner query is doing (in PhStartDates) is that it is getting each phone number and the first outbound call date; then the trick is getting done by the floor parts, they are calculating day differences from the first outbound call date to each inbound or outbound date and getting the week number since the first ourbound call date. the group by these floors are ensuring we are getting the first dates within these groups. I hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks Ashraf. I appreciate your response.